# adding numbers in I variable in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a calculation and I need to make a for loop that when it's calculated I need to add 3 up,
the code I use is:

```
var fields = [fieldname140, fieldname879, fieldname886],
result = 0.00;

for(var i = 1, h=fields.length; i<h; i++)
{
 if(ABS(1-fields[i])<ABS(1-result)) result = fields[i];
}

 return result;
```

is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: what have you **tried** so far?

Comment: I have tried to use fields[i+3] but that would leave it empty. after that I tried to put it fields[i] + 3 but that calculated 3 with my calculation but that is not what I want in example I want that fieldname1 will become fieldname4 when it went trought my for loop

Comment: Could you explain more what do You intend to do?

Comment: Is it intended to have an infinite loop caused by `h = fields.length`? **Assigning** `fields.length`to a variable `h`will always be `true`.

Comment: thanks filburt I didn't knew to add this code to stackoverflow (I litterly just made my account) I have added the full code now hope this helps a little bit more

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate() {
    var fields = ['fieldname140', 'fieldname879', 'fieldname886']; var result = '';
    var newFields = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        var index = fields[i];
        var indexName = index.substring(0, 9);
        var indexVal = parseInt(index.substring(9));


        result = indexName + (indexVal + 3);
        newFields.push(result);
        //console.log(result);
    }
    //console.log(newFields);
    return newFields;
}
```

Call this calculate function and get new fields array with increment.

Comment: thanks for the tip unfortunately I still get an empty string and it won't calculate.

Comment: This answer should have more detail. Please explain how/why this code would be helpful.